# Non-Standard Inner Product and Orthogonality of Matrix Subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

The row (column) space and the (left) null space of a matrix, are orthogonal subspaces under the standard dot product. However, I’m interested in understanding how this relationship might change if we consider a different inner product.

Suppose we have a vector space endowed with a non-standard inner product. Would these spaces still be orthogonal under this new inner product? If not, what kind of relationship might they have?

Edit 1:
There is no specific context, it is just a (trivial?) question that came to mind while I was trying to prove the orthogonality between those subspaces.

For instance, let's focus only on the orthogonality between row and null spaces. Let $\pmb{A}=\begin{bmatrix}\pmb{a}_{1}\\ \vdots \\ \pmb{a}_{m} \end{bmatrix}$ be an $m\times n$ real matrix, where $\pmb{a}_{i}$ is the *i*-th row vector of $\pmb{A}$. The row space of $\pmb{A}$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ spanned by its row vectors, *i.e.,* $\mathrm{row}\,\pmb{A}=\mathrm{span}(\{\pmb{a}_{1}, \; \dots, \; \pmb{a}_{m}\})$. On the other hand, the null space of $\pmb{A}$ is the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ consisting in the solution set of the homogeneous linear system $\pmb{Ax}=\pmb{0}$, *i.e.,* $\mathrm{ker}\,\pmb{A}=\{\pmb{x} \in  \mathbb{R}^n \mid \pmb{Ax}=\pmb{0}\}$. The row-by-column perspective of matrix multiplication allows us to rewrite the latter matrix equation as $\begin{bmatrix}\pmb{a}^{\mathrm{T}}_{1}\pmb{x}\\ \vdots \\ \pmb{a}^{\mathrm{T}}_{m} \pmb{x} \end{bmatrix}=\pmb{0}$. This shows that the null space of $\pmb{A}$ contains only those vectors of $\mathbb{R}^n$ orthogonal to the row vectors of $\pmb{A}$ with respect to the standard inner product, hence $\mathrm{row}\,\pmb{A}=(\mathrm{ker}\,\pmb{A})^\perp$.

The same reasoning applies to the other two subspaces of $\pmb{A}$.

However, unlike matrix multiplication, the definition of orthogonal complement between two subspaces depends on the particular inner product used. Hence my question.

Edit 2:
Ok, let's look at the specific example suggested in the comments:

$$
\pmb{A}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\pmb{u}=(u_1, u_2), \quad \pmb{v}=(v_1, v_2), \quad  \langle \pmb{u},\pmb{v} \rangle = 2u_1v_1+u_1v_2+u_2v_1+2u_2v_2
$$

Each of the four subspaces of $\pmb{A}$ is a line. In particular, we have that:
$$
\begin{align}
& \mathrm{row}\,\pmb{A}=a(1,1) \\
& \mathrm{ker}\,\pmb{A}=b(1,0) \\
& \mathrm{col}\,\pmb{A}=c(1,0) \\
& \mathrm{ker}\,\pmb{A}^\mathrm{T}=d(0,1)
\end{align}
$$

for $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. The orthogonality between the row space and the null space holds. Indeed:
$$
a(1,1) \cdot b(1,0) = \langle a(1,1), b(1,0) \rangle = 0, \quad \forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}
$$

On the other hand, this is not true for the column space and the left null space of $\pmb{A}$, where the dot product:
$$
c(1,0) \cdot d(0,1) = 0, \quad \forall c,d \in \mathbb{R}
$$
while the inner product:
$$
\langle c(1,0), d(0,1) \rangle = cd, \quad \forall c,d \in \mathbb{R}
$$

This should prove that the row (column) space and the (left) null space of a matrix are always orthogonal complements only under the standard inner product, right?

Comment: That depends on how you define the "row-space" in this new context. In a sense, the standard inner product is the justification for talking about the row space of a matrix in the usual way.

Comment: In any case, note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), and answerers are discouraged from answering questions without this context. It would be helpful if you could edit your question to say a bit, for instance, about what inspired you to ask this question, what you've tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you may have.

Comment: If you can think of nothing to add here, I would suggest that you look at the specific example of the matrix 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&1\\0&0}
$$
and the inner product $\langle \vec u, \vec v\rangle = 2u_1v_1 + u_1 v_2 + u_2v_1 + 2u_2v_2$ and edit the question to say what you have found.